# Simulating a bungee jump [C++]

Tags: c++, class, physics

I am trying to simulate a bungee jump, given the mass of the subject, the spring constant of the bungee cord, the initial length of the cord, and other values necessary in finding the acceleration, velocity, and distance fallen of the subject. I have to make use of basic classes and arithmetic in order to complete this project.

here is the class i have created:

```
#include "FallingObject.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

FallingObject::FallingObject(float mass, float surfaceArea, float bungeeSpringConstant, float      bungeeUnstretchedLength) {
    this->mass = mass;
    this->surfaceArea = surfaceArea;
    this->bungeeSpringConstant = bungeeSpringConstant;
    this->bungeeUnstretchedLength = bungeeUnstretchedLength;
}
float FallingObject::getMass(){
    return this->mass;
}
float FallingObject::getSurfaceArea(){
    return this->surfaceArea;
}
float FallingObject::getBungeeSpringConstant(){
    return this->bungeeSpringConstant;
}
float FallingObject::getBungeeUnstretchedLength(){
    return this->bungeeUnstretchedLength;
}
void FallingObject::simulateTimeStep(float deltaT){

    float g = 9.81, timeStep = 0.0;
    float fWeight, fFriction, fSpring, fTotal;
    float currentV, currentD, currentA;
    velocity = 0.0;
    distance = 0.0;
    acceleration = 0.0;


    //Acceleration @ timeStep = 0:
    fWeight = mass * g;
    fFriction = (-0.65) * surfaceArea * velocity * abs(velocity);
    fSpring = (-1) * bungeeSpringConstant * distance;
    fTotal = fWeight + fFriction + fSpring;
    currentA = fTotal / mass;


    //Velocity @ timeStep = 0
    currentV = acceleration * timeStep;


    //Distance @ timeStep = 0
    currentD = velocity * timeStep;


    //increment values
    timeStep += deltaT;
    acceleration += currentA;
    velocity += currentV;
    distance += currentD;


}
float FallingObject::getFallDistance(){
    return this->distance;
}
float FallingObject::getVelocity(){
    return this->velocity;
}
float FallingObject::getAcceleration(){
    return this->acceleration;
}
```

here is the main function:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   // arguments in order:
   // mass (70kg)
   // surface area (0.2m^2)
   // spring constant for the bungee cord (21.7)
   // unstretched length of bungee cord (30m)
   FallingObject fallingObject(70.0f, 0.2f, 21.7f, 30.0f);

   vector<float> elapsedTimes;
   vector<float> distances;
   vector<float> velocities;
   vector<float> accelerations;

   ofstream outFile("bungee_data.txt");

   // time step zero
   elapsedTimes.push_back(0.0f);
   distances.push_back(fallingObject.getFallDistance());
   velocities.push_back(fallingObject.getVelocity());
   accelerations.push_back(fallingObject.getAcceleration());

   float simulationTime = 60; // 60 seconds
   float deltaT = 0.01;       // 0.01 seconds
   int timeSteps = (int)(simulationTime / deltaT);

   for (unsigned int t = 1; t < timeSteps; t++) {
       fallingObject.simulateTimeStep(deltaT);
       elapsedTimes.push_back(t * deltaT);
       distances.push_back(fallingObject.getFallDistance());
       velocities.push_back(fallingObject.getVelocity());
       accelerations.push_back(fallingObject.getAcceleration());


   }

   for (int i = 0; i < timeSteps; i++){
       outFile << elapsedTimes[i] << ",";
       outFile << distances[i] << ",";
       outFile << velocities[i] << ",";
       outFile << accelerations[i] << endl;
   }



   return 0;
}
```

the problem i am having is that the values are not updating and I am unable to determine the cause.

can anyone please provide some assitance with this problem?

Comment: I do not see `main`, or any program starting point.   How are you running this code?

Comment: Where do you call simulateTimeStep? Where ever you are calling this function, you need to put it inside of a loop with some exit condition.

Comment: Give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as mentioned by @abelenky, to help diagnosing your problems.

Comment: love the debugger and it shall love you back

Comment: @d0ublehel1x You may want to debug your code stepping through and watching how variable values actually change in 1st place, before asking here. If you can tell about some particular anomalies you cannot explain from the standard references, you're welcome back for asking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Didn't I say _"**before** asking here"_?

Answer (score 1):

You're performing the calculation with `timeStep`, which is local to the function and set to zero each time it's called.

Since `deltaT` *is* the time step, just use that:

```
currentV = acceleration * deltaT;
currentD = velocity * deltaT;
```

(If you would continuously add `deltaT` to the "time step", it wouldn't be a step but the total elapsed time.)

You also reset these variables on each call:

```
velocity = 0.0;
distance = 0.0;
acceleration = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

At every call of `FallingObject::simulateTimeStep` you are resetting your state-describing values `velocity` and `distance`. You have to save them permanently.